# rapid-miner formating datsets with many parameter

Tags: classification, modeling, prediction, rapidminer

Problem with too many parameter to put as columns into example set.

My problem-task is that I have customers with a unique ID and they have parameter (binomial) and I would like to predict the value of certain target variables, so far only one but possible multiple.
In my test case I used the following input dataset, see meta data, each customer is represented in a row and the parameter are in the columns – simply the usual way.

**meta data:**
*Role - Name - Type* 
id   - Customer_Id  - integer 
label - Target - binominal 
regular - Para1 - binominal 
regular - Para2 - binominal 
regular - Para3 - binominal 
regular - Para4 -  binominal 
**dataset:** 
*Customer_Id -  Target -  Para1  - Para2 -  Para3 -  Para4* 
1 -  M -  1  - 0 -  1 -  0 
2 -  V  - 1 -  0  - 0 -  1 
3 -  M -  0  - 1 -  1 -  1

=> With Naïve Bayes I get great prediction results in the test case with limited dimensions.

Problem with the actual dataset: 
I have some 100,000s of parameter and the number is growing a lot. The actual number of active parameter for a customer is very small and so the table would be extremely large and sparse. So my idea was to use the following dataset format as input: 
**meta data:**
*Role -  Name -   Type* 
id -  Customer_Id  - integer 
label - Target -   binominal 
regular -  ActivePara -  polynominal 
**data:**
*Customer_Id -  Target  - ActivePara* 
1 -  M -  Para1 
1 -  M -  Para3 
2 -  V -  Para1 
2 -  V -  Para4 
3 -  M  - Para2 
3 -  M -  Para3 
3 -  M -  Para4

BUT now I do not get consistent predictions per customer what I get is something like this

*Customer_Id -  Target  - ActivePara  - Prediction of Target 
1 -  **M -  Para1 -  V** 
1 -  M -  Para3 -  M 
2 -  V -  Para1 -  V 
2 -  V -  Para4 -  V 
3 -  M -  Para2 -  M 
3 -  M -  Para3 -  M 
3 -  **M -  Para4 -  V**

**But I want/need the target prediction per customer_id to be consistent.**

How do I need to set up the input data/ the model to get the result!

**Thanks a lot in advance for any hints and help!!!**

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the over simplification of the problem. you have converted multiple attributes in to one poly nominal attribute, so to naive bayes it is a single attribute which can take multiple values, it cannot take in to account the co-occurrence of active parameters.

I will suggest a better option to manage your model. the structure that works best for you is

*Customer_Id - Target - Para1 - Para2 - Para3 - Para4* 
1 - M - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

change this to 
*Customer_Id - Target - ( number = decimal value of the binary representation of all the parameters)

if you have 3 params
p1 p2 p3
1  1  0

then the decimal value of 110 (binary) is 6.

This should help

Comment: Thanks - I think I got what you mean. But this way I lose the power to dive deeper into analysis on certain parameter. If I combine all parameter I cannot later identify which one of them are really having the significant influence on the target variable. Or? Because the algorithm will only work on the combination of them. Now when I use decision tree instead of naive bayes I can really see which parameter are the distinguishing ones.

Comment: Yeah.. There is always some trade off.. if you have thousands of parameters and your model is not scaling, then this approach will help u scale or other option is use limited set of features, give the feature selection extension of RapidMiner a try